# android html font color NumberFormatException on device HTC D816D,HTC D816W

Tags: android, html

I show html to the textview in android.Every thing goes well on large part devices.But on the HTC D816D,HTC D816W，I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: &quot;red&quot;
at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:361)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:352)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.parseUnsignedIntAttribute(XmlUtils.java:160)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToUnsignedInt(XmlUtils.java:130)
at android.content.res.StringBlock.getColor(StringBlock.java:346)
at android.content.res.StringBlock.applyStyles(StringBlock.java:252)
at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:135)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.getPooledString(AssetManager.java:314)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:727)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:97)
at android.widget.TextView.&lt;init&gt;(TextView.java:943)
at android.widget.TextView.&lt;init&gt;(TextView.java:669)
```

and the html string is just like:

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!<font color="red">Android</font></string>
```

The problem is the keyword color="red".Some device can't parse this code.I have searched the internet,but got nothing.
1.How to deal with such particular devices type bugs in the android?
2.Is setting the color value #ff0000 in the textview not from html a common solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello this color is not defined in some devices so you can set color directy into attribute <font color="#ff0000">

Comment: try to use `<string name="hello_world">Hello world! <![CDATA[ <font color="red">Android</font> ]]></string>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use  and other tags like that in android resources strings. It is trying to read and parse your html tag and it fails. You can set it dynamically from html like this

```
String s = "<font color=#ff0000>Android</font> <font color=#000000>something else</font>";`
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Also, you can dynamically create strings using `Spannable`

```
Spannable word = new SpannableString("Hello World! Android");        
 word.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 14, word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```